# Silent errors in ember components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Recently i have found strange behaviour in my application

if i have a problem in component, i don't receive any errors, application loads with blank screen and after several tens seconds i receive a deprecation:
`[deprecation id: ember-views.render-double-modify]`
without any clues what is the real problem

it might happen when i pass non existing closure action to component,
or event if i manually throw error in computed property in component

it happens in all recent versions of Ember (2.4.6+)

I can not reproduce such behaviour in empty application, so probably problem in my application or addons, but i have no idea how to find what catches errors.

Any ideas how to find source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in ember-data, which swallowed exceptions from run loop
https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4533
it was fixed in 2.8.1 version of ember-data